# Input text moving when pasting text - Webkit

Tags: forms, input, webkit

I'm having an odd problem in webkit browsers (Actually it was reported happening in Chrome by client, but I can only see it in Safari for Mac at the moment). When typing in the input, the text is fine, but as soon as text is pasted into the input, the text jumps to the top. I really don't know what could be causing it. Is this a known issue? Is it something I've done wrong? I can't seem to figure it out and would really appreciate any help. Here is what it looks like:

http://jsfiddle.net/JDhYf/1/

Thank you in advance,

Necronar

Answer (score 0):

"line-height:" fixed the problem, visually. However, it does seem to be a bug in webkit browsers. [Reported on Feb. 12 2012 on code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113875)